# How can I tell if http request is complete using the request npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request, httprequest

I am using the request npm library(https://github.com/request/request), and would like to know when the http get request is complete. Does this request module support an end listener?

`request(url, callback).on('end',function(){})`

If not, how can I determine when the request is complete?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation (and the examples)? You even linked to the page. What other help do you need?

Comment: @FelixKling As mentioned, I need to determine when the request is complete. No where in the documentation do I see information on that. If you do, please let me know.

Comment: It says: `request(options, callback)` and further down: *"The callback argument gets 3 arguments: [...] The third is the `response` body (`String` or `Buffer`, or JSON object if the `son` option is supplied)"*. I assume that if you are able to access the response, the request is completed. Similar for the examples: https://github.com/request/request#examples

Comment: Here is what I am trying to achieve. I have an array of ids and for each id I want to do a get request. The problem I am facing is that the request completes in the incorrect order.
`async.each(arrayOfIds, eachRequest, function(err) { 
  if(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
});

function eachRequest(id, callback) {
  var url = baseUrl + id;
  request(url, requestCallback);
}

function requestCallback(error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  } else {
    var result = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(result);
  }
}`

Comment: Sounds like you really want to use `async.eachSeries()` to perform iteration in series instead of parallel with `async.each()` then.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The request is complete when `callback` is called. Otherwise if you don't use a callback, you can listen for the `response` event and listen for `end` on the response stream passed to the `response` event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.